# App Engine tasks that target backend get 503 even if backend is running

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

A lot of tasks are failing to execute because they get 503 from the target backend. This is very strange because most tasks execute but it seems that if it got 503 once it will always be getting 503.

I try to run the tasks manually and the backend is active and serving but if the task had failed with 503 previously it will fail again with a 503 on the spot.

Any clue?